# Array of length 17 is only being iterated over 9 times by forEach loop

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script

I have an array that's length is 17, but the forEach loop only iterates through it 9 times. This skipping of loops is also happening with for...of loops and a for(let i=0; i<collection.length; i++) loop.

Array:

```
[ { info: 
     { name: 'aname',
       type: 'Topic',
       number: '3.11',
       id: '1.1.2.9' },
    children: [],
    skills: [] },
  { info: { name: 'othername', type: 'Topic', number: '3.10', id: '1.1.2.8' },
    children: [],
    skills: [] },
  { info: 
     { name: 'someothername',
       type: 'Topic',
       number: '3.9',
       id: '1.1.2.7' },
    children: [],
    skills: [] },
  { info: { name: 'howmanyfillersisthis', type: 'Topic', number: '3.8', id: '1.1.2.6' },
    children: [],
    skills: [] },
  { info: 
     { name: 'e',
       type: 'Topic',
       number: '3.7',
       id: '1.1.2.5' },
    children: [],
    skills: [] },
  { info: 
     { name: 'a',
       type: 'Topic',
       number: '3.6',
       id: '1.1.2.4' },
    children: [],
    skills: [] },
  { info: 
     { name: 'b',
       type: 'Topic',
       number: '3.5',
       id: '1.1.2.3' },
    children: [],
    skills: [] },
  { info: { name: 'c', type: 'Topic', number: '3.4', id: '1.1.2.2' },
    children: [],
    skills: [] },
  { info: 
     { name: 'd',
       type: 'Topic',
       number: '3.3',
       id: '1.1.2.1' },
    children: [],
    skills: [] },
  { info: 
     { name: 'f',
       type: 'Topic',
       number: '3.2',
       id: '1.1.1.2' },
    children: [],
    skills: [] },
  { info: 
     { name: 'g',
       type: 'Topic',
       number: '3.1',
       id: '1.1.1.1' },
    children: [],
    skills: [] },
  { info: 
     { name: 'h',
       type: 'Enduring Understanding',
       number: '4',
       id: '1.1.4' },
    children: [],
    skills: [] },
  { info: 
     { name: 'i',
       type: 'Enduring Understanding',
       number: '3',
       id: '1.1.3' },
    children: [],
    skills: [] },
  { info: 
     { name: 'j',
       type: 'Enduring Understanding',
       number: '2',
       id: '1.1.2' },
    children: [],
    skills: [] },
  { info: 
     { name: 'k',
       type: 'Enduring Understanding',
       number: '1',
       id: '1.1.1' },
    children: [],
    skills: [] },
  { info: { name: 'l', type: 'Unit', number: '1', id: '1.1' },
    children: [],
    skills: [] },
  { info: { name: 'm', type: 'Course', number: '1', id: '1' },
    children: [],
    skills: [] } ]
```

loop:

```
collection.forEach((element, index) => {
    times++;
    let self_id = element["info"]["id"];
    seeking_id = self_id.slice(0,self_id.length-2);
    //console.log(`${self_id} --> ${seeking_id}`);
    collection.forEach((elem)=>{
      if(elem["info"]["id"]===seeking_id){
        elem["children"].push(element);
        collection.splice(index,1);
      }
    });
  });
```

the times++ is for me to see how many times it was looped

Why is the loop skipping some values of the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop doesn't skip some values of the array. The problem is that you are modifying your array (removing elements as you go through your loop) in this line of code `collection.splice(index,1);`. You can verify that if you check your array length every time you execute your loop.

Based on my understanding in your code, you are trying to move the array elements as children if the parent id was found in the array list.

You can refer to this sample code to achieve that:

```
  Logger.log(collection.length);
  var toBeRemoved = [];
  collection.forEach((element, index) => {


    let self_id = element["info"]["id"];
    seeking_id = self_id.slice(0,self_id.length-2);
    Logger.log(self_id);
    Logger.log(seeking_id);
    //console.log(`${self_id} --> ${seeking_id}`);
    collection.forEach((elem,idx)=>{
      if(elem["info"]["id"]===seeking_id){
        Logger.log("found remove index "+index);
        Logger.log("found at index "+idx);
        elem["children"].push(element);
        ///collection.splice(index,1);
        toBeRemoved.push(index);
      }
    });
  });

  toBeRemoved.reverse();
  toBeRemoved.forEach(index=>{
    collection.splice(index,1);
  });
```

### Output:

`[{info={id=1, name=m, type=Course, number=1}, skills=[], children=[{children=[{children=[], skills=[], info={number=4, name=h, type=Enduring Understanding, id=1.1.4}}, {skills=[], children=[], info={number=3, type=Enduring Understanding, id=1.1.3, name=i}}, {info={type=Enduring Understanding, name=j, id=1.1.2, number=2}, children=[{info={number=3.11, name=aname, type=Topic, id=1.1.2.9}, children=[], skills=[]}, {info={name=othername, number=3.10, type=Topic, id=1.1.2.8}, children=[], skills=[]}, {children=[], skills=[], info={type=Topic, id=1.1.2.7, name=someothername, number=3.9}}, {skills=[], info={name=howmanyfillersisthis, id=1.1.2.6, number=3.8, type=Topic}, children=[]}, {skills=[], children=[], info={number=3.7, type=Topic, id=1.1.2.5, name=e}}, {children=[], info={type=Topic, number=3.6, name=a, id=1.1.2.4}, skills=[]}, {children=[], skills=[], info={name=b, number=3.5, type=Topic, id=1.1.2.3}}, {skills=[], children=[], info={name=c, number=3.4, id=1.1.2.2, type=Topic}}, {children=[], skills=[], info={number=3.3, type=Topic, name=d, id=1.1.2.1}}], skills=[]}, {skills=[], children=[{info={number=3.2, id=1.1.1.2, name=f, type=Topic}, skills=[], children=[]}, {info={number=3.1, name=g, type=Topic, id=1.1.1.1}, children=[], skills=[]}], info={number=1, type=Enduring Understanding, name=k, id=1.1.1}}], skills=[], info={id=1.1, number=1, type=Unit, name=l}}]}]`

### What it does?

1. Check each array elements and move it to the elements if the parent id was found.
2. Instead of removing the element that was moved, just list all the array indexes that was moved
3. Reverse the order of the array indexes to be removed. The reason why reverse is necessary is that when we removed the index, the array indexes will not adjust since we remove the elements at the end of the list.

Comment: Please let me know if your goal is different from what I understood so I could update the solution. But nonetheless, the root cause for your loop count was explained in the answer

Comment: Thank you! I don't know how I forgot about that.

Comment: Also you understood my goal perfectly, so don't worry about that

Comment: glad to hear that :)